# Bluetooth on android - Is it possible to connect to more than one bluetooth device at the same time?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to more than 1 bluetooth device at the same time, But I am getting the next error:

```
java.io.IOException: Host is down
```

at the second  time I am trying to connect :

```
 private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
  mmSocket.connect();
```

Is it possible to connect to more than one bluetooth device at the same time?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, normally up to 8 devices can exist in a (what's called) piconet. Basically one master may communicate with up to 7 other devices. That's how the Bluetooth protocol is specified.

Comment: Hi Jurid thank you for your answer- can you give me code example for mulitple connection?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one at hand, but I found the [Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) quite useful.